# Loading textfile

Tags: c#, winforms

**Problem in short**:  Load saved map that was saved as an textfile where 0 = empty button/tile, 1 = wall, 2 = character and it back up on another form.

**Longer more detailed explanation**: 
I have been working on a winform game for a bit, I know it isn't the best way to make a game but I am just trying to get accustomed.  Currently I have two forms, one to create a map, another to load it up.  On my map creation form I am able to say the length and width of my map, when I generate it, it displays tiles(that are buttons) with the length and width dimensions specified( 3 buttons wide, 4 buttons long.)

Now I am able to save it as numbers that were given values for that certain image ( 0 is for no image just the button, 1 is for a button with an wall, 2 is for a button with a character.).  What I am trying to do now is read the text file and load up the tiles with the correct dimensions and image that was originally given.

My images are placed onto radio buttons which determine which image to play, I did tags for this

```
  public SaveForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            rNoImage.Tag = 0;
            rNoImage.Click += Check;

            rCharacter.Tag = 1;
            rCharacter.Click += Check;

            rWall.Tag = 2;
            rWall.Click += Check;

        }
 private void square_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
        {
            Map square = (Map)sender;
            Map.Type = (MapType)selected;

            switch (selected) 
            {
                case 0:
                    square.Image = null;  
                    break;
                case 1:
                    square.Image = Properties.Resources.Character; 
                    break;
                case 2:
                    square.Image = Properties.Resources.Wall;
                    break;                
            }
        }
 private void Check(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            RadioButton toolBtn = (RadioButton)sender; 
            selectedTool = (int)toolBtn.Tag; 
        }
```

When saving I have done the following:

```
private void saveButton(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SaveFileDialog sfg = new SaveFileDialog();
            sfg.Filter = "Game File(*.game)|*.game";
            if (sfg.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(sfg.FileName))
                {
                    sw.WriteLine($"{rows},{cols}");
                    foreach (Map square in (pnlGameBoard.Controls))
                    {
                        sw.WriteLine(square.GetString());

                    }
                    var output = MessageBox.Show("saved", "saved success", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
                }
            }
        }
```

I have a component class set up for this called ***Map*** in this I have an enum to show the types

```
 public enum MapType 
    {
        None, 
        Character, 
        Wall, 
    }
```

Now I have my map being made as an Button, when clicked based on selected radio button image changes on the button.

```
  public partial class Map : Button 
    {
        int row; 
        int col;

        public MapType Type { get; set; } 

        const int OFFSET = 20;
        const int MapSize = 50;

        public Map()
        {

        }

        public Map(int row, int col) 
        {
            this.row = row;
            this.col = col;

            this.Size = new Size(MapSize, MapSize);
            this.Location = new Point(OFFSET + col * MapSize, OFFSET + row * MapSize);
            Type = MapType.None;
        }
        public string GetString() 
        {
            return $"{(int)Type}";
        }
    }
```

So I am able to save it, but my issue now is loading it up on the second form which I am struggling to do.

What I have managed so far is:

```
private void openButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   OpenFileDialog ofg = new OpenFileDialog();
   ofg.Filter = "Game File(*.game)|*.game;"
   if(ofg.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
   {
      File.ReadAllLines(ofg.FileName);

      //Not Sure what to do next here
   }
}
```

Apologize for the lengthy post but I wanted to make sure that I am clear enough, thanks.

The layout for the textfile that I saved would be:

```
3,3
1
1
1
0
2
0
1
1
1
```

3,3 represents the length and width that was chosen, I will most likely remove this as I am only trying to read the numbers below, top row is wall,wall,wall(1,1,1), middle row is empty button, character, empty button, bottom row is wall,wall,wall.

I have looked at some different examples here that involve reading 2D matrixes from files to 2D int arrays but I am not sure how to actually implement this in my above code or how it works.

Comment: Is that the real code? 'Cause `square` is not defined. Should it be `tile` instead? Also shouldn't it be `foreach (Map tile in pnlGameBoard.Controls.OfType<Map>())`?

Comment: That's my bad, it's supposed to be square but I must've been thinking about tile when I was writing the code here.  And personally with the saving I haven't had any issues, I'm guessing your way would just be a neater/better method of doing it though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've created a way to represent a `Map` as a string, but not the other way around. One way to create a `Map` from a `string` is to write a `public static Map Parse(string input)` method that takes in a `string` and returns a `Map`. One tricky part is that we will also need to pass in the `row` and `col`, since those are private fields and not settable outside of the constructor.

For example:

```
public class Map : Button
{
    // Existing code exluded from this example

    public static Map Parse(string input, int row, int col)
    {
        if (input == null) return null;
        int typeVal;
        if (!int.TryParse(input, out typeVal))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("input must be a valid integer");
        }

        // Return a new map with row, col, and Type
        return new Map(row, col) {Type = (MapType) typeVal};            
    }
}
```

Now that we can create a `Map` with the proper `Type` from a `string` (along with the `row` and `col`), we can create a couple of loops: one to loop through each row, and on each row we loop through each column, creating a `Map` and adding it to our panel:

```
// You might need to set some standard sizes for the Map controls
private int mapHeight = 50;
private int mapWidth = 300;

// Not sure where these are actually defined
private int rows;
private int cols;

private void openButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var ofg = new OpenFileDialog {Filter = "Game File(*.game)|*.game;"};

    if (ofg.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        // Read all our lines into an array
        var lines = File.ReadAllLines(ofg.FileName);

        // And now do the opposite of how we created the text file:
        // First, set the rows and cols based on the first line
        // (some validation should be done here, but this works with "3,3")
        var rowsCols = lines[0].Split(',');
        int.TryParse(rowsCols[0], out rows);
        int.TryParse(rowsCols[1], out cols);

        // Next, create Maps from the rest of the lines and add them to our controls
        // Note we should validate that lines.Length = rows * cols + 1
        var line = 1; // This gets incremented below, so we read each line

        for (int row = 0; row < rows; row ++)
        {
            for (int col = 0; col < cols; col++)
            {
                // Create a map from the line, row, and column using our new method
                var map = Map.Parse(lines[line++], row, col);

                // Set the layout by rows and columns (?)
                map.Width = mapWidth;
                map.Height = mapHeight;
                map.Left = (col + 1) * mapWidth;
                map.Top = (row + 1) * mapHeight;

                // Hook up the Click event so our images load on click
                map.Click += square_Click;

                // Add the control to our panel
                pnlGameBoard.Controls.Add(map);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That makes a lot more sense, I appreciate you taking the time to help out, thanks!

Comment: One issue I found though, how would I make them appear with the proper image?  As of now they are appearing as blank buttons.

Comment: I think you need to hook up the `Click` event, right? I've added this line to the sample: `map.Click += square_Click;`. And if you just want to set the image directly, then you can call `map.Click()`. Or copy the code from that event into the code that reads from the file and set the image immediately. Otherwise you may need to save some indication of what image to load in the file, and add that to the parsing somewhere.